# Output of spliting array does not come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array of ints as input, return true if it is possible to split the array into two so that the sum of the numbers on the left is equal to the sum of the numbers on the right.

**MyApproach**

I added elements from front and  back till half of their length and added their Sum.When I found them as equal I return true,else I return false

```
public boolean canSplit(int[] arr)

{
    int k=0;
    int SumF[]=new int[1];
    int SumB[]=new int[1];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length/2;i++)
    {
       SumF[k]=arr[i]+SumF[k];
    }
    for(int j=arr.length-1;j>=arr.length/2;j--)
    {
                   SumB[k]=arr[j]+SumB[k];

    }

    if(SumF==SumB)
    return true;
    else
    return false;


}


Parameters       Actual Output  Expected Output

'{10,11,12,5,4}'    false       true
```

> MyQuestion:Can Anyone guide me what I have done wrong?

Comment: The problem does not say the sub-arrays have to be the same size? Are you sure they have to be the same size?

Comment: ` int SumF[]=new int[1];, int SumB[]=new int[1];` ,why not just use `int`

Comment: Why are you storing the sum into an `integer array` size 1? Why not use an `int`?

Comment: @SaviourSelf Yes my mistake.I can a variable to store their value.

Comment: It seems you have many errors: one is testing identity of two arrays allocated separately. That will always be false in your code. More significantly, I think the problem is not understood. With the parameter you show: a) the length is not even, so you can't split it in half and b) 10+11=>21, and 12+5+4=>21. You need to create two sums (ints), not two arrays (`SumF` and `SumB`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not about splitting in *half* but just splitting in *two*. Right now, you only check *one* particular way to split the array. You have to check all the ways.

One way to do this is to find the sum of all the numbers in the array, then loop the numbers, calculate the running sum of all the numbers up to that place, and see whether that's half of the total sum.

```
public static boolean canSplit(int[] array) {
    int total = IntStream.of(array).sum();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : array) {
        sum += i;
        if (sum == total - sum) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I wish my homework would have been **that** easy ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k  My code is working for the input ({10,11,12,5,4}),{1,3,5,-3,-5,2,-1,0,1,-1}.But I am not getting expected output.

Comment: @Jasonarora Works fine for me, returning `true` for both. What are you getting?

Comment: @Jasonarora When you say "my code" do you mean the code from your original question, or the code from my answer when you run it?

Comment: @tobias_k The code i have written.Your code works well in all situation I learned that.On the basis of your idea I have written code for that.Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jan haha :) You always start with basics by the way.If things doesn't work out for 1 hr.I write here what I am doing wrong after screwing my head.